# Jquery UI Accordion won't collapse when created dynamically with web database

Tags: jquery-ui-accordion

This accordion works fine when it's on the page by itself, but when I dynamically populate the individual title/content pairs via a web database, the title and content are uncollapsed. Is there a problem with the way I implemented it?

The rest of the database (inserting dictionary term and definition in 2 different fields) is functioning flawlessly without the accordion function. Understandablhy, I want to integrate the accordion so there's less scrolling for the user.

Here is the code implemented, then the code (commented out) straight from the source for comparison:

```
function showRecords() {
  var results = '';
  results.innerHTML = '';
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
     tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function(tx, result) {
        dataset = result.rows;
        for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {
           item = dataset.item(i);
           results.innerHTML = '<div id="accordion">';
           results.innerhtml += '<h3>' + item['term'] + '</h3><div><p>' + item['definition'] + '<button class="glossaryButton2" onClick="loadRecord('+i+')">Edit</button> <button  class="glossaryButtonDel" style="float:right;" onClick="deleteRecord(' + item['id'] + ')">Delete</button></p><hr></div>';
           }
        });
});
results.innerHTML += '</div>';
// TRIED: $('#accordion').html(results).accordion({collapsible: true});
// TRIED: $("#accordion").accordion({collapsible: true});
// getter
var collapsible = $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "collapsible" );
// setter
$( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "collapsible", true );
exportRecords();
}
```

(Explanation of $('#accordion').html(results).accordion({collapsible: true}); : "The accordion call only works on matching elements in the DOM at the point it is called. Since you are adding the accordion dynamically, there is nothing to match. You need to re-apply the accordion after loading the new content." I think this is the point at which I'm clueless. )

```
/* The HTML of original accordion:

<div id="accordion">

   <h3>Section 1</h3>
   <div>
      <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi.</p>
   </div>

</div>
*/
```

This above problem is not unique to Jquery UI. I've had exactly the same problem with 4-5 other Javascript accordions - I keep trying! I always try the accordion by itself; if it works, then I integrate it with the database + innerHTML -- and find it quits collapsing.

(FYI: This code is sharing space with Zurb Foundation 3, and uses the Jquery that came with it. It works fine with the above HTML accordion version when used apart from the database, so that can't be the issue.)

Comment: Hard to parse that line in my head, but are you missing a closing </div>?

Comment: tmack: no, it's right above the // TRIED statements.

Comment: Any errors in the JS console?

Comment: There are no errors for this page in Google's Tools.